# MVC3 Testing ModelState excluding property errors in a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, modelstate, validationsummary

I've done some searching on Google and Stack Overflow but can't find the answer to this one.

I have the following in my view

```
@if (!Html.ViewData.ModelState.IsValid)
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)<br />
}
```

I'm only interested in model errors but the test will return true if property errors are found. How do I test just model errors?

I may need to clarify here, I want to do the test to stop the `<br />` being written out when there is a property error but no model error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you go to the source of ValidationSummary, you can find

```
IEnumerable<ModelState> modelStates = null;
if (excludePropertyErrors) { 
    ModelState ms;
    htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.TryGetValue(htmlHelper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix, out ms);
    if (ms != null) {
        modelStates = new ModelState[] { ms }; 
    }
} 
else { 
    modelStates = htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.Values;
}
```

So I think you could make a method like that

```
public static bool ModelStateHasModelErrors(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper) {
   ModelState ms;
   htmlHelper.ViewData.ModelState.TryGetValue(htmlHelper.ViewData.TemplateInfo.HtmlFieldPrefix, out ms);
   return ms != null;
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but to only show model errors the parameter should be set to true. I've edited the original post to try to clarify what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: @WhiteWade oh oh oh, you're right, sorry. Well, edited, but it doesn't help you. I'll try to find a better way.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Almost perfect. Just had to change `this HtmlHelper helper` to `this HtmlHelper htmlHelper`